How to Use Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Stream Binder with GlobalKTable
I'm working on a Spring Cloud Stream application where I need to write from a existing topic into a global store. So I want that each instance of my app / pod is consuming and writing the whole existing topic into a KeyValueStore. The important thing is I just want to use the Store and no addtional function.
So I know if I stream from an input to an output topic I can do it like this (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2933)
But I don't have this function in the first place, so I tried to use a Consumer with the GlobalKTable like so:
@Configuration
@Log4j2
public class KafkaStreamsConfig {

    @Bean
    public Consumer<GlobalKTable<UUID, String>> globalResultConsumer() {
            return input -> log.info(
                    "GlobalResultConsumer is consuming in: {}",
                    input.queryableStoreName()
                );
    }
}

And:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: globalResultConsumer
    stream:
      bindings:
        globalResultConsumer-in-0:
          destination: result-topic
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
        streams:
          bindings:
            globalResultConsumer-in-0:
              consumer:
                materializedAs: global-result-store
                keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$UUIDSerde
                valueSerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                configuration:
                  specific.avro.reader: true

It seems to be working fine, but is that 100% correct configuration? And how I could log the consumed messages which are written into the store?

Looks like the code you showed above is fine. What is your specific question? Your consumer function is consuming records as GlobalKTable instatnces from the result-topic. That should work. If something is not working, please update the question with more specific details. Thanks.

@sobychacko Ok thanks for your answer, like I said, I would like to be able to track / log the consumed messages somehow. But at least you say it is working like that. Because they are not so many examples with just a Consumer and also not so many with GlobalKTable. I also was confused because usually you have access to the consumed Messages like Consumer<KStream<Object, String>, so I was not sure if my way is the correct one.

@sobychacko Would it make any sense to get public access to KTableValueGetterSupplier<K, V> thruogh the GlobalKTable interface? Maybe this way I would be able to log the messages similar to the GlobalStateStore?

If you have a Consumer<GlobalKTable>, then anything publicly available on the GlobalKTable API is fine to use in the implementation code. Here is an example using GlobalKTable for joins - not necessarily your use case, but will show some usage patterns: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/main/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-global-table-join/src/main/java/kafka/streams/globalktable/join/KafkaStreamsGlobalKTableJoin.java#L45

@sobychacko But this is a Function, I just have a Consumer, I just want to read from an existing topic into my Store while logging (or be able to access)  the consumed messages, for example to trigger an pending request asynchronously. In your example I have access because I stream from one topic to another and I save the joined / changed / manipulated messages in my Store, but I just want to consume a topic into a Store without any change to the messages. If it is not possible tell me or give me an minimal example, because your answer makes no sense.
